# my batch brings records and identifies if they're acc or cont for a particular field. How do I test it?

Tags: unit-test, batch, code-coverage

```
@isTest
public class ALN_Integration_BatchTest {
    public static testMethod void  metodoTest(){
        ALN_Integration__c rec = new ALN_Integration__c();            
        rec.First_Name__c = 'Kinder';
        rec.Last_Name__c = 'Lak';
        rec.Email__c = 'klak@gmail.com';
        rec.ALN_ID_Account_PMC__c = '001452';
        rec.Account_Name__c = 'KinderAccount';
        insert rec;   
        Test.startTest();
        Database.executeBatch(new ALN_Integration_Batch());
        Test.stopTest();
        
        ALN_Integration__c recAC = new ALN_Integration__c();            
        recAC.First_Name__c = 'AC_Test';
        recAC.Last_Name__c = 'ACln';
        recAC.Email__c = 'acln@gmail.com';
        recAC.ALN_ID_Account_AC__c = '001453';
        recAC.Account_Name__c = 'AC_rec_Test';
        insert recAC;
        
        List<Account> listAcc = [SELECT ID, Name from Account];
        system.assert(!listAcc.isEmpty());              
          
       
    }
```

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here to really help you, please [edit] your question to include the class/method that you're trying to test. Testing boils down to making sure that you execute enough lines of code in your tests (coverage is determined by which lines of code get executed through a test), and that depends on the data that you set up in your test. If you want to execute a specific method, you need to ensure that you call that method. If you want to execute the lines of a specific `if()` statement, you need to set up test data to ensure that `if` condition is satisfied.

Comment: Your test class should likely have more than a single test method in it. Without getting too far into the nitty-gritty, if you have an if-else if-else, then you want to have one test to cover the `if`, a second test to cover the `else if`, and a third test to cover the `else`.